# Hide Top navigation in SharePoint except specific group

Tags: sharepoint-online, global-navigation, current-navigation

Actually, I created 10 tabs in top navigation bar using **Navigation settings under Site settings** `/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx`

And I created specific group (Non-Users) and added few users in it.

Now I need to hide 3 tabs in navigation for Non-Users group persons.

For remaining person which are not mentioned Non-Users group, they can visible or see 10 tabs in navigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use target audience. It will work perfectly.**

Follow below steps :

1. GoTo `/_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx`
2. In the Structural Navigation section Click on the link/tab that you want to hide for Non-Users of the group
3. Click on the edit option 
   [image]
4. In the `Audience` property specify the group name that should be able see the link and click OK. 
   [image]
   Here Only users that are present in this group will be able to see this link. And for other users this link will be hidden.

Comment: Yeah @Rohit, Actually I already tried with this but need to create two groups. **1. More than 500 users (So Added Everyone from AD) 2. Non-Users group but they belongs to organizations.** Now how to separate this non-user from AD